# Windows 10 - Permission Difference Between CommonAppDataFolder and User's Application Data Folder

Tags: windows, windows-10

My application keeps failing with an access denied error when writing to a file in Windows 10. When the file is in C:\ProgramData\, it fails. As a test, I moved it to C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\ and the access denied error went away. I've also noticed that when right clicking on the file when its in ProgramData, I need administrative access to delete or rename the file. In AppData\Roaming, I do not. However, there doesn't appear to be any security differences between the two folders. I can't figure out why one works and the other doesn't, any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: *ProgramData* requires admin permissions to write to, and is typically used for static files required by an application. *AppData* (whether user or common) is designed for data that can be changed, and is accessible to the user (in the case of User\AppData) or all users (in the case of CommonAppData). *CommonAppData* is writable to all users.

Comment: the CommonAppDataFolder in Visual Studio is C:\ProgramData, so thats why I brought it up. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: That would be the static data, written by the installer using the administrator account. It's not typically written to after installation. Changing data should be either in `Users\Public\AppData` (all users) or `Users\<Username>\AppData` for the current logged in user.